# validating checkbox checked in Orbeon FormBuilder

Tags: orbeon

How do I validate a checkbox in FormBuilder? I'm looking for something like checkbox.isAny. I'm working on very complex branching on a survey form. If any are boxes are checked, I will show another question in a survey, and so on.

Right now, my formula is looking for checkbox1 or checkbox2 or checkbox3. That works when any 1 checkbox is checked. But when checkbox1 AND checkbox2 is checked the next question does not appear. There must be a way to check for any boxes.

I'm new, so if you can point me to a wiki or online learning source for xforms validation and xpath, I'd greatly appreciate it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a question (say named `question`) if any of the checkboxes for a field (say named `checkboxes`) is checked, maybe because if any of the checkboxes is set users need to provide more information, then set the Visibility for `question` to:

```
$checkboxes != ''
```